# How to move master to branch in magit?

Tags: magit

This is how I move master to branchX in git:

```
$ git checkout master            #move HEAD to master
$ git branch -f branchX HEAD     #move by force, HEAD to branchX
```

Is there a way to do that in Magit?

In this example, I want to move master to wstudent-topic2:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that it does what you think it does... `git branch -f <branchname> <startpoint>` will reset `<branchname>` to commit `<startpoint>`. In your case, this will not affect `master` branch in any way. Instead, this will basically, alias `master` as `branchX`. I'm not sure why would you want to do it, and I never tried to do this from `magit`. Can you explain what's the end-result you want to achieve?

Comment: @user2867994 You will have to explain what you mean by "move master to branch in magit". Currently it is impossible to tell for sure what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you want to do but since my attempt to get you to explain in more detail what you want (or to get moderators of this site to close the issue because you don't do that) have failed, I am answering some questions that you did not *actually* ask.

Based on the screenshot (but for the most part ignoring what you have written) I am going to assume that your question is one of:

**How do I merge `topic2` into `master`?**

Type <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> `topic2` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

If you put the cursor on the `add f2` line first, then you could also just <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> because `topic2` would be the default in that case.

**How do I reset `master` so that it points at the same commit as `topic2`?**

In a situation like the one in the screenshot you should just merge `topic2` as I have just described. But if the situation looked like this instead:

```
* [master] something else
| * [topic2] add f2
|/
* add f1
* add f0
```

Then a merge would result in this:

```
* [master] Merge branch 'topic2'
|\
| * [topic2] add f2
* | something else
|/
* add f1
* add f0
```

Maybe that's what you want - I have no way of knowing. But if you want this instead:

```
* [master] [topic2] add f2
* add f1
* add f0
```

then move to the `[topic2] add fs` line and type <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: @user2867994 I am still hoping that eventually someone will upvote this answer so that this question doesn't forever remain "unanswered". Given the question, you won't get a better answer.